# Add new item in many to many field via api in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm calling an API to update the my liked_products many to many model in Django but, when calling the prod ID to add the item to the list, I get the error:

AttributeError at /api/customer/like_product/
'ReturnDict' object has no attribute 'liked_products'

Here is my API:

```
@csrf_exempt
def updated_liked_products(request):
    customer = get_user(request)
    if not customer:
        return JsonResponse({'invalid token'})

    customer_details = CustomerDetailSerializer(CustomerDetails.objects.get(
    customer=customer)).data
    
    customer_details.liked_products.add(request.data['prodId'])
    customer_details.save()

    return JsonResponse({"success": 'updated'})
```

Customer Details Model:

```
  age = models.IntegerField(default="21", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(
        default='', max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    nick_name = models.CharField(
        default='', max_length=254, blank=True)
    average_order = models.FloatField(default="0.0", blank=True)
    completed_orders = models.IntegerField(default="0", blank=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer_type = MultiSelectField(
        choices=CUSTYPE, default=CUSTYPE, max_length=100)
    current_selfie = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='sefies/', blank=True, default='')
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_signin = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    liked_products = models.ManyToManyField('Product')
    needs_help_with = MultiSelectField(
        choices=CATEGORIES, max_length=1000, default='')
    phone = models.CharField(
```

I am using Postman to update the data like this so I can see the liked product field but, cannot access it.:

[image]

Comment: request.data['prodId'] this should be some id of existing instance of Product Table or it should be the instance of Product Table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having this error because you're trying to access `liked_products` attribute on a serialized `data` that is an instance of `ReturnDict` and not `CustomerDetails`.

It seems like there is not much point in the serializer usage in this API so you should be able to achieve what you want with just this:

```py
@csrf_exempt
def updated_liked_products(request):
    customer = get_user(request)
    if not customer:
        return JsonResponse({'invalid token'})

    customer_details = CustomerDetails.objects.get(customer=customer)
    
    customer_details.liked_products.add(request.data['prodId'])

    return JsonResponse({"success": 'updated'})
```